# How Can I Activate Button Classes in Frontend?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, frontend

There are buttons as you can see in the .cshtml code I shared. I want to change the type of these buttons. However, no matter what I do, the buttons come as default when I run the application in the browser.

[image] it is what i see. But i want to one of them like that -> [image]

```
<h2>SIMPLE CALCULATOR</h2>
<form asp-action="Calculator" method="post">

    <div class = "border-dark">

               <div class = "form-group">
                 <label for = "FirstNumber">First Number</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstNumber" name="FirstNumber" value="@Model.FirstNumber"/>
               </div>

               <div class = "form-group">
                 <label for = "SecondNumber">Second Number</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SecondNumber" name="SecondNumber" value="@Model.SecondNumber"/>
               </div>

               <button type= "submit" class="btn-btn-info" id="addition" value="addition" name="method">+</button>
               <button type= "submit" class="btn-btn-danger" id="substraction" value="substraction" name="method">-</button>
               <button type= "submit" class="btn-btn-warning" id="multiplication" value="multiplication" name="method">*</button>
               <button type= "submit" class="btn-btn-default" id="division" value="division" name="method">/</button>

                <div class = "form-group">
                 <label for = "Result">Result</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ResultNumber" name="ResultNumber" value="@Model.ResultNumber"/>
               </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: _"I created Index for simple calculator but even I choose class of buttons, buttons are coming default in the frontend when I run the code."_ - I'm sorry but what you've written is not clear and understandable English - I don't understand what you're trying to do or what the problem is - especially "buttons are coming default in the frontend" - please rewrite your question.

Comment: @Dai sorry for that. What I'm trying to say is there are buttons as you can see in the .cshtml code I shared. I want to change the type of these buttons. However, no matter what I do, the buttons come as default when I run the application in the browser.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "change the type of these buttons" and "buttons come as default"?

Comment: @Dai for example, `class="btn-btn-info"` for '+' button but button does not coming that class. Style of button is same. I'll add screenshots to the topic.

Comment: It sounds like your stylesheet isn't loading then. Use your browser's DevTools window to find out why.

Comment: @Dai do you think there is no fault in code? Because i tried in Edge and Chrome but results are same.

Answer (score 1):

If your web app is using Bootstrap (Bootstrap is included with asp.net mvc web app templates).
Bootstrap 5 buttons -
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/
The bootstrap documation states:

```
class=“btn btn-primary”
```

You’re adding an extra dash “-“ between btn btn. Try removing the first dash.